# Checkbox cannot get a param when I mixed it with text box for the same name input in a form

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, checkbox

I want checkboxes for user to define the length they need. It could be 11, 13, 15 or custom which they can type into the text box. However, when I test by clicking one checkbox, it does not capture 11, 13 or 15 (but if I type the number in the text box, I get that "length"=>"number",). How to mix checkbox and text for input type in the the form.

/.html.erb

```
<div class="form-group" id="div_checkbox2">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="checkbox">
   Length :
  </label>
  <div class="col-sm-8 ">
   <label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input name="length" type="checkbox" value="11"/>
    11
   </label>
   <label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input name="length" type="checkbox" value="13"/>
    13
   </label>
   <label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input name="length" type="checkbox" value="15"/>
    15
   </label>
   <label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input name="length" type="text" maxlength="2" style="border-radius: 5px; height: 25px; width: 25px"/>
    custom (odd number only)
   </label>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I see two problems in this question:

- You are using checkboxes when you need to use radio buttons. The main difference (in usage, but also programming) is that using radio buttons you can only select one of the options, and using checkboxes you can select as many options as you want (which does not seem to be what you are trying to achieve)
- You are sending several parameters using the same key. If the user selects the lengths 11, 15 and my_custom_length, the values are sent to the server using the following conceptual format:

  length=11, length=15, length=my_custom_length

At this point the server does not know what is the value you really wanted to send for the length field.

I suggest using a radio button with four options (11, 13, 15, other), and a text input with the value inserted when the user selects "other" in the radio buttons.